# How to convert out/ref extern parameters to F#

Tags: f#, pinvoke, extern, ref-parameters

I've got a C# extern declaration that goes like this:

```
    [DllImport("something.dll")]
    public static extern ReturnCode GetParent(IntPtr inRef, out IntPtr outParentRef);
```

How to translate that to F#?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try something like the code below. I don't know what `ReturnCode` is, so the code below expects it is an integer. For any more complex type, you'll need to use `[<Struct>]` attribute as in the answer referenced by A-Dubb.

```
type ReturnCode = int

[<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("something.dll")>]
extern ReturnCode GetParent(System.IntPtr inRef, System.IntPtr& outParentRef);
```

To call the function, you'd write something like this:

```
let mutable v = nativeint 10
let n = GetParent(nativeint 0, &v)
```

BTW: Could you also post a sample C code that implements the function in `something.dll`? If yes, we could try running the solution before sending an answer...

Comment: that works great!  However - the old C# declaration allowed me to do "let (n, v) = GetParent input".  Any way to modify the code to allow that syntax?

Comment: oh, and ReturnCode is just an enum based off uint32

Comment: Seems to be related to the "hidebysig" decorator in CIL.  In red gate reflector the C# method has it, whereas the F# method does not.  Does F# offer hidebysig?  (I'm still trying to figure out what that even means).

Comment: @Dax - I'm not sure if there is any way to get the nice syntax (could be related to some F# meta-data - the compiler might allow the syntax only on external definitions). I'm not sure it has something to do with hidebysig (afaik that's something to do with hiding or overloading).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this similar question will point you in the right direction. Looks like he used attributes at the parameter level for "in" and "out" [F# syntax for P/Invoke signature using MarshalAs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689460/f-syntax-for-p-invoke-signature-using-marshalas)

Comment: Yeah.  At least however I interpreted it.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else trying to use F# with EnvDte via PInvoke this may help:

```
[<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("ole32.dll")>] 
extern unit CreateBindCtx(System.IntPtr inRef, IBindCtx& outParentRef);
[<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("ole32.dll")>]
extern unit GetRunningObjectTable(System.IntPtr inRef, IRunningObjectTable& outParentRef);
```

which apparently is slightly incorrect, but appears to work. the definition should be:

```
[<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("ole32.dll")>] 
extern int CreateBindCtx(System.IntPtr inRef, IBindCtx& outParentRef);
[<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("ole32.dll")>]
extern int GetRunningObjectTable(System.IntPtr inRef, IRunningObjectTable& outParentRef);
```